# Seeding data "The seed entity for entity type ... cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property ID"

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to seed a few static tables using Entity Framework owned models. Below is my setup. I'm working with sub/owned models. i cannot seem to correctly seed the submodels. when generating a new migration. i get the error at the bottom of the post.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Base model

```
public class STATIC_HorecaCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public LocalizedText Description { get; set; }

}
```

Sub-model

```
[Owned]
public class LocalizedText
{
    public string NL { get; set; }
    public string DE { get; set; }
    public string FR { get; set; }
    public string EN { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
{

    public DBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {  }

    public DbSet<STATIC_HorecaCategory> STATIC_HorecaCategories { get; set; }
    
 
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
         builder.Entity<STATIC_HorecaCategory>()
             .OwnsOne(p => p.Description)
             .HasData(new STATIC_HorecaCategory { Id = 1, Description = new LocalizedText { NL = "Cafe", EN = "Cafe", DE = "Cafe", FR = "Cafe" }});
        
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

When generating a new migration:

```
2022-09-28T11:25:01Z Cloning into '.'...
2022-09-28T11:25:02Z Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '18.205.93.1' to the list of known hosts.
2022-09-28T11:25:18Z Reset branch 'develop'
2022-09-28T11:25:18Z Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
2022-09-28T11:25:18Z Pulling cache layers for index.docker.io/easyc0de/helios-cms:latest-dev...
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z Done!
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z KernelVersion: 5.4.0-1068-aws
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z Components: [{u'Version': u'20.10.15', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': {u'KernelVersion': u'5.4.0-1068-aws', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2022-05-05T13:17:24.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.41', u'MinAPIVersion': u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'4433bf6', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.17.9'}}, {u'Version': u'1.6.8', u'Name': u'containerd', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6'}}, {u'Version': u'1.1.4', u'Name': u'runc', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d'}}, {u'Version': u'0.19.0', u'Name': u'docker-init', u'Details': {u'GitCommit': u'de40ad0'}}]
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z Arch: amd64
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z BuildTime: 2022-05-05T13:17:24.000000000+00:00
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z ApiVersion: 1.41
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z Platform: {u'Name': u'Docker Engine - Community'}
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z Version: 20.10.15
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z MinAPIVersion: 1.12
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z GitCommit: 4433bf6
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z Os: linux
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z GoVersion: go1.17.9
2022-09-28T11:26:17Z Buildkit: Starting build for index.docker.io/easyc0de/helios-cms:latest-dev...
2022-09-28T11:26:20Z WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release
2022-09-28T11:26:23Z WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format has been removed and the configuration file will be ignored
2022-09-28T11:26:23Z WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format has been removed and the configuration file will be ignored
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-debug
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #1 transferring dockerfile: 799B done
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #1 DONE 0.1s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #2 [internal] load .dockerignore
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #2 transferring context: 2B done
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #2 DONE 0.1s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.9-bullseye-slim
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #3 DONE 0.4s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #4 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #4 DONE 0.4s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #5 importing cache manifest from index.docker.io/easyc0de/helios-cms:latest-dev
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #5 DONE 0.0s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #6 [internal] load build context
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #6 DONE 0.0s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 [base 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.9-bullseye-slim@sha256:3fb88dac384cabbd07146cfb5317f90eaadb2b19e3b928bb03f8992f7342ae4a
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.9-bullseye-slim@sha256:3fb88dac384cabbd07146cfb5317f90eaadb2b19e3b928bb03f8992f7342ae4a 0.0s done
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:3fb88dac384cabbd07146cfb5317f90eaadb2b19e3b928bb03f8992f7342ae4a 1.11kB / 1.11kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:9bbfbed0f66ed02e8de90ec46e45ea46367b1263604f6d9869b0e7a2a21c65db 1.37kB / 1.37kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:fd48163689297fd6096083525da1a3caebacc60ab5110a3fdd7b59ed952042d4 3.25kB / 3.25kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 0B / 31.40MB 0.1s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 0B / 15.17MB 0.1s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 2.10MB / 31.63MB 0.1s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 3.15MB / 15.17MB 0.2s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 4.19MB / 31.63MB 0.2s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 9.44MB / 31.40MB 0.4s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 5.24MB / 15.17MB 0.4s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 8.04MB / 31.63MB 0.4s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 7.34MB / 15.17MB 0.5s
2022-09-28T11:26:24Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 15.73MB / 31.63MB 0.5s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 14.68MB / 31.40MB 0.6s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 12.21MB / 15.17MB 0.6s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 24.12MB / 31.40MB 0.8s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 15.17MB / 15.17MB 0.8s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 23.07MB / 31.63MB 0.8s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 30.49MB / 31.40MB 0.9s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 15.17MB / 15.17MB 0.8s done
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 25.17MB / 31.63MB 0.9s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:7b9388913c3cc3dacffa41ae2bb30c18b54cc5f522fa6ef2faacf48b0dff6020 156B / 156B 0.9s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #8 resolve docker.io/library/node:15 1.1s done
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #8 DONE 1.1s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 [base 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.9-bullseye-slim@sha256:3fb88dac384cabbd07146cfb5317f90eaadb2b19e3b928bb03f8992f7342ae4a
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 29.36MB / 31.63MB 1.0s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:7b9388913c3cc3dacffa41ae2bb30c18b54cc5f522fa6ef2faacf48b0dff6020 156B / 156B 0.9s done
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:871ef3419da3410a47aa97b7655d8543add053e27cac5c5922ff3ee1f75793cd 0B / 9.46MB 1.0s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 31.40MB / 31.40MB 1.1s done
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 31.63MB / 31.63MB 1.2s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:871ef3419da3410a47aa97b7655d8543add053e27cac5c5922ff3ee1f75793cd 9.46MB / 9.46MB 1.2s
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 31.63MB / 31.63MB 1.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 sha256:871ef3419da3410a47aa97b7655d8543add053e27cac5c5922ff3ee1f75793cd 9.46MB / 9.46MB 1.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:25Z #7 extracting sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430
2022-09-28T11:26:30Z #7 extracting sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 5.0s
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #7 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1 0.0s done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 31.40MB / 31.40MB 1.0s done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 31.63MB / 31.63MB 1.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1 1.11kB / 1.11kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:3f5873abb5240a10f3abee05c6f89933d2da0b06037a0532aeb7ddd7959f8252 2.01kB / 2.01kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:05057078be7d5b0fdc8424f965a11d416639373f9388ecaeb4e2af2ce5bbc1c4 7.17kB / 7.17kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:871ef3419da3410a47aa97b7655d8543add053e27cac5c5922ff3ee1f75793cd 9.46MB / 9.46MB 1.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:7b9388913c3cc3dacffa41ae2bb30c18b54cc5f522fa6ef2faacf48b0dff6020 156B / 156B 0.9s done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:c3514d10142f3a43d3037bc770248d6093c76d46a47ebe8ac4232c8b29d9eaab 25.37MB / 25.37MB 3.0s done
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 82.84MB / 148.14MB 6.7s
2022-09-28T11:26:31Z #9 sha256:8b2829492cd27a90e4bde8169f4c4e3d2e6c17be2354f230684b05d40ea6df90 12.89MB / 12.89MB 2.4s done
2022-09-28T11:26:32Z #9 sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 91.23MB / 148.14MB 7.7s
2022-09-28T11:26:32Z #9 sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 101.71MB / 148.14MB 8.1s
2022-09-28T11:26:33Z #9 sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 111.25MB / 148.14MB 8.7s
2022-09-28T11:26:33Z #9 sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 123.67MB / 148.14MB 9.3s
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #9 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:608bba799613b1ebf754034ae008849ba51e88b23271412427b76d60ae0d0627 776B / 776B done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:5c8e883ae793121a3f7e56308d6436c0173f502c83f88eeefb53a5b28bce4b85 2.21kB / 2.21kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:3d3f41722daf1a77c34d6eade6676bbffa2d6a2a21095de2ab0c427a5c942fc9 7.83kB / 7.83kB done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:bfde2ec33fbca3c74c6e91bca3fbcb22ed2972671d49a1accb7089c9473cac12 45.38MB / 45.38MB 4.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:787f5e2f10471c11a2064774062aeeb400f76e9eef1ca768156a23678f005f3e 11.29MB / 11.29MB 2.4s done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:7b6173a10eb81a318ed53df74c8b80d29656f68194682e51f46f9b7b24c6ba03 4.34MB / 4.34MB 2.6s done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:dc05be471d511acb4574f2f3630582527220c59d0abf0b8b905769916b550da7 49.76MB / 49.76MB 5.3s done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 69.21MB / 214.35MB 8.6s
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 extracting sha256:bfde2ec33fbca3c74c6e91bca3fbcb22ed2972671d49a1accb7089c9473cac12 3.2s
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:bd821d20ef8c23c1c474d4b014889cfd2fcffb063a86dea8769347a630d0d558 4.19kB / 4.19kB 5.6s done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:6041b69671c6bb6164f007bfac852155d68772a9abbf2c88d8c2ab15401db93e 33.79MB / 33.79MB 8.0s done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:989c5d2d23137beb4982cf38660054e8f2e88ebeaac8a06734360b525d7193af 2.38MB / 2.38MB 8.6s done
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 sha256:4b57d41e83915c9043fa19a6fd09316e84f9cff1a41d7b29589c35e0e29ba2a9 291B / 291B 8.7s
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z
2022-09-28T11:26:34Z #9 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #9 sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 136.31MB / 148.14MB 10.4s
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #9 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #6 [internal] load build context
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #6 transferring context: 84.16MB 9.8s
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #6 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 106.00MB / 214.35MB 9.9s
2022-09-28T11:26:35Z #8 sha256:4b57d41e83915c9043fa19a6fd09316e84f9cff1a41d7b29589c35e0e29ba2a9 291B / 291B 8.7s done
2022-09-28T11:26:36Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 117.44MB / 214.35MB 10.5s
2022-09-28T11:26:37Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 130.02MB / 214.35MB 11.2s
2022-09-28T11:26:37Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 142.61MB / 214.35MB 11.6s
2022-09-28T11:26:38Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 159.05MB / 214.35MB 12.5s
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 174.82MB / 214.35MB 13.3s
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #8 extracting sha256:bfde2ec33fbca3c74c6e91bca3fbcb22ed2972671d49a1accb7089c9473cac12 8.2s
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #6 [internal] load build context
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #6 transferring context: 133.53MB 13.4s done
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #6 DONE 13.8s
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 187.79MB / 214.35MB 13.5s
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 200.28MB / 214.35MB 13.7s
2022-09-28T11:26:39Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 211.81MB / 214.35MB 13.9s
2022-09-28T11:26:41Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:41Z
2022-09-28T11:26:41Z #7 [base 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.9-bullseye-slim@sha256:3fb88dac384cabbd07146cfb5317f90eaadb2b19e3b928bb03f8992f7342ae4a
2022-09-28T11:26:41Z #7 extracting sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 15.7s
2022-09-28T11:26:41Z #7 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:41Z
2022-09-28T11:26:41Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:26:42Z #8 sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 214.35MB / 214.35MB 16.4s done
2022-09-28T11:26:42Z #8 extracting sha256:bfde2ec33fbca3c74c6e91bca3fbcb22ed2972671d49a1accb7089c9473cac12 11.9s done
2022-09-28T11:26:43Z #8 extracting sha256:787f5e2f10471c11a2064774062aeeb400f76e9eef1ca768156a23678f005f3e
2022-09-28T11:26:44Z #8 extracting sha256:787f5e2f10471c11a2064774062aeeb400f76e9eef1ca768156a23678f005f3e 1.4s done
2022-09-28T11:26:44Z #8 extracting sha256:7b6173a10eb81a318ed53df74c8b80d29656f68194682e51f46f9b7b24c6ba03
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #8 extracting sha256:7b6173a10eb81a318ed53df74c8b80d29656f68194682e51f46f9b7b24c6ba03 0.8s done
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #9 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #9 sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 148.14MB / 148.14MB 12.9s done
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #9 extracting sha256:31b3f1ad4ce1f369084d0f959813c51df0ca17d9877d5ee88c2db6ff88341430 15.8s done
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #9 extracting sha256:7ed415b4bd19c2b83ef768757b22c5156111db042fd62be4263ba200b4c0c8d0 1.4s done
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #9 extracting sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 0.6s
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #9 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z
2022-09-28T11:26:45Z #7 [base 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.9-bullseye-slim@sha256:3fb88dac384cabbd07146cfb5317f90eaadb2b19e3b928bb03f8992f7342ae4a
2022-09-28T11:26:48Z #7 extracting sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 4.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:48Z #7 extracting sha256:871ef3419da3410a47aa97b7655d8543add053e27cac5c5922ff3ee1f75793cd 0.3s
2022-09-28T11:26:49Z #7 extracting sha256:871ef3419da3410a47aa97b7655d8543add053e27cac5c5922ff3ee1f75793cd 1.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:49Z #7 DONE 25.4s
2022-09-28T11:26:49Z
2022-09-28T11:26:49Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:26:49Z #8 extracting sha256:dc05be471d511acb4574f2f3630582527220c59d0abf0b8b905769916b550da7 3.9s
2022-09-28T11:26:55Z #8 extracting sha256:dc05be471d511acb4574f2f3630582527220c59d0abf0b8b905769916b550da7 9.0s
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z #8 extracting sha256:dc05be471d511acb4574f2f3630582527220c59d0abf0b8b905769916b550da7 10.6s done
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z #9 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z #9 extracting sha256:357910a178d4d646acde36bf2c2a95fc59893a78c92a56a47ef8cc89627f850a 4.2s done
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z #9 extracting sha256:7b9388913c3cc3dacffa41ae2bb30c18b54cc5f522fa6ef2faacf48b0dff6020 done
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z #9 extracting sha256:c3514d10142f3a43d3037bc770248d6093c76d46a47ebe8ac4232c8b29d9eaab 6.5s done
2022-09-28T11:26:56Z #9 extracting sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683
2022-09-28T11:26:57Z #9 ...
2022-09-28T11:26:57Z
2022-09-28T11:26:57Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:26:57Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48
2022-09-28T11:27:02Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 5.2s
2022-09-28T11:27:06Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:27:06Z
2022-09-28T11:27:06Z #9 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1
2022-09-28T11:27:06Z #9 extracting sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 9.3s
2022-09-28T11:27:06Z #9 ...
2022-09-28T11:27:06Z
2022-09-28T11:27:06Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:27:07Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 10.3s
2022-09-28T11:27:12Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 15.4s
2022-09-28T11:27:16Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:27:16Z
2022-09-28T11:27:16Z #9 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1
2022-09-28T11:27:16Z #9 extracting sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 19.3s
2022-09-28T11:27:16Z #9 ...
2022-09-28T11:27:16Z
2022-09-28T11:27:16Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:27:17Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 20.5s
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z #8 ...
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z #9 [build 1/9] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.401-bullseye-slim@sha256:61b6b1075bb9058742b567dbc3070163c6fa8d1440335fa94280882de21fe3b1
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z #9 extracting sha256:c65769fdd163d4fcba401982b5b50f0f78ec1970e68c45fb6671a8864c977683 22.4s done
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z #9 extracting sha256:8b2829492cd27a90e4bde8169f4c4e3d2e6c17be2354f230684b05d40ea6df90 1.1s done
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z #9 DONE 57.4s
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z
2022-09-28T11:27:21Z #8 FROM docker.io/library/node:15
2022-09-28T11:27:22Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 25.5s
2022-09-28T11:27:28Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 30.7s
2022-09-28T11:27:29Z #8 extracting sha256:55fab5cadd3cc0fb680b701177abf2c36dde0de9f1e3f3b233aab8ba622c4d48 32.1s done
2022-09-28T11:27:29Z #8 extracting sha256:bd821d20ef8c23c1c474d4b014889cfd2fcffb063a86dea8769347a630d0d558 done
2022-09-28T11:27:30Z #8 extracting sha256:6041b69671c6bb6164f007bfac852155d68772a9abbf2c88d8c2ab15401db93e 0.1s
2022-09-28T11:27:33Z #8 extracting sha256:6041b69671c6bb6164f007bfac852155d68772a9abbf2c88d8c2ab15401db93e 3.7s done
2022-09-28T11:27:33Z #8 extracting sha256:989c5d2d23137beb4982cf38660054e8f2e88ebeaac8a06734360b525d7193af
2022-09-28T11:27:34Z #8 extracting sha256:989c5d2d23137beb4982cf38660054e8f2e88ebeaac8a06734360b525d7193af 0.3s done
2022-09-28T11:27:34Z #8 extracting sha256:4b57d41e83915c9043fa19a6fd09316e84f9cff1a41d7b29589c35e0e29ba2a9 done
2022-09-28T11:27:34Z #8 DONE 70.2s
2022-09-28T11:27:43Z
2022-09-28T11:27:43Z #10 [base 2/3] COPY --from=node:15 . .
2022-09-28T11:27:49Z #10 ...
2022-09-28T11:27:49Z
2022-09-28T11:27:49Z #11 [build 2/9] COPY --from=node:15 . .
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z #11 ERROR: cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/sfuaw0vux73qvd6k16sjt57ur/merged/usr/share/doc/perl-base with file
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z #10 [base 2/3] COPY --from=node:15 . .
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z #10 ERROR: cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ipvsri718cl52hcggq0ssj1r8/merged/usr/share/doc/perl-base with file
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z ------
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z > [base 2/3] COPY --from=node:15 . .:
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z ------
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z ------
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z > [build 2/9] COPY --from=node:15 . .:
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z ------
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z ERROR: failed to solve: cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/sfuaw0vux73qvd6k16sjt57ur/merged/usr/share/doc/perl-base with file
2022-09-28T11:28:04Z Build failed using Buildkit (1)
```

The actual error message:

> The seed entity for entity type 'STATIC_HorecaCategory.Description#LocalizedText' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'STATIC_HorecaCategoryId'.

Answer (score 0):

Owned Types need shadow key for the relation table. In your case the shadow key is `STATIC_HorecaCategoryId`

```
builder.Entity<STATIC_HorecaCategory>()
     .HasData(new {Id = 1});

builder.Entity<STATIC_HorecaCategory>()
    .OwnsOne(p => p.Description)
    .HasData(new 
    { 
        STATIC_HorecaCategoryId = 1, 
        Description = new LocalizedText 
        {
            NL = "Cafe", 
            EN = "Cafe",
            DE = "Cafe", 
            FR = "Cafe" 
        }
     });
```